# C++ covariant returning type application

Tags: c++, design-patterns, covariance, covariant

I wanted to ask about covariant return type and a possible (not) application. I thought I had discovered some new design pattern, but sadly it does not work :(

Let's start with an example:

```
// test.h 
class B {public: virtual B* getSelf() {return this;} };
class D : public B { public: D* getSelf() {return static_cast<D*>(this);} };

void compute(B* something); 
void compute(D* something);

// test.cpp 
int main() 
{
B* b = new D(); 
compute(b->getSelf()); // This calls compute(B*), not compute(D*) 
}
```

Any idea of why it does not work?

PS I apologize for the poor formatation

Edit: Of course, it correctly calls compute(D*) if I use a cast in the main.

Edit #2: I'm trying to avoid switch as much as I can :)

Answer (score 0):

Function overload resolution is done at compile time and depends on the static type of your expression not the dynamic one.

The type of `b->getSelf()`is `B*`since that's the return type of the member function `getSelf` when called on an instance of type `B`.
It doesn't matter at this time that `b` will point to a `B`, a `C` or a `D` at runtime, whatever child instance you store in that pointer won't affect its static type.

That said, what you are trying to achieve seems to be solvable with simple polymorphisme (make `compute` a member function) or if you don't want that you can use [double dispatching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is as I imagined. Simple polymorphisme does not apply in my specific case because I would like to separate the computation part from the objects. Double dispatching in C++ has been treated in the Alexandrescu Modern C++ Design book, so I guess I should look into it again.

Comment: My goal is to separate the objects from the computation part, like STL, without compile time limitations (i.e. it should work at runtime).

Comment: @user3770392 If you want a real generic separation of objects and computation you'll need a stronger common "interface" (could be a concept rather and a real class) between your objects. STL achieves this thanks to templates and the concept of iterators which nearly all containers implement. Separating computation from the objects (as opposed to making them member functions) by coding one overload for each one of them doesn't bring much genericity or ease of maintenance, it just brings you more cpp files :)

Comment: Yep, it makes sense. The only thing I have doubts is about the expandibility. For instance, using the normal polymorphic approach, every time I want to add a computation ability, I have to add a function member,  making my class too large and bloated :(